# Why do my second-level futures execute serially?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-future

I am trying to replicate the examples in the [topology vignette of the *future* package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-3-topologies.html). To quote:

> Futures can be nested in R such that one future creates another set of futures 
>   and so on. This may, for instance, occur within nested for loops [...]

There is a part where the author uses `plan(list(multicore, multicore))` (further arguments and `tweak` omitted) to process two futures synchronously who in term each processes four futures synchronously. This should equal to eight futures processed synchronously.

However, when I try to reproduce this with the code below, I see that the second level of futures is processed sequentially. What am I doing wrong?

## MCVE

```
library(future)
library(ggplot2)
plan(list(multiprocess, multiprocess))


# Run for a random amount of time and return start and stop time
startStop <- function(){
  start <- Sys.time()
  x <- runif(1, 1, 3)
  Sys.sleep(x)
  stop <- Sys.time()
  return(data.frame(start = start, stop = stop))
}

nGrp <- 3
nCV <- 4

l <- rep(list(NULL), nGrp)


for(i in seq_along(l)){
  l[[i]] <- future({
    m <- rep(list(NULL), nCV)
    for(j in seq_along(m)){
      m[[j]] <- future(startStop())
    }
    m <- lapply(m, value)
    m <- do.call(rbind, m)
    m
  })
}
l <- lapply(l, value)
d <- do.call(rbind, l)
d$iGrp <- rep(seq_len(nGrp), each = nCV)
d$iCV <- rep(seq_len(nCV), times = nGrp)

d$x <- paste(d$iGrp, d$iCV, sep = "_")
d$iGrp <- as.character(d$iGrp)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, ymin = start, ymax = stop, color = iGrp)) + geom_linerange() + coord_flip()
```

[image: time evolution of futures execution]

## Expectation

[image: expectation]

## Session Info

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /opt/Bio/R/3.4.3/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/Bio/R/3.4.3/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.1 future_1.8.1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17     devtools_1.13.4  munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2
 [5] R6_2.2.2         rlang_0.1.6      httr_1.3.1       plyr_1.8.4      
 [9] globals_0.11.0   tools_3.4.3      parallel_3.4.3   grid_3.4.3      
[13] gtable_0.2.0     git2r_0.21.0     withr_2.1.1      yaml_2.1.16     
[17] lazyeval_0.2.1   digest_0.6.15    tibble_1.4.2     codetools_0.2-15
[21] curl_3.1         memoise_1.1.0    compiler_3.4.3   pillar_1.1.0    
[25] scales_0.5.0     listenv_0.7.0
```

Comment: What is `returnStartStop`?

Comment: @F.Privé Ah drat, I forgot to include it. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) here:  This is because there is a built-in protection against nested parallelism.  Without it, you would overload your computer with too many parallel processes, which would not only overheat it but also slow down the overall performance.

I've updated the 'Future Topologies' vignette for the next release with the following section:

> **Built-in protection against recursive parallelism**
>
> Above we have processed either the outer or the inner set of future in parallel.  What if we want to process both layers in parallel? It's tempting to use:
>
> ```
> plan(list(multiprocess, multiprocess))
> ```
>
> Although this does not give an error, we will find that the inner layer of futures will be processed sequentially just as if we would use `plan(list(multiprocess, sequential))`. This behavior is due to the built-in protection against nested parallelism. If both layers would run in parallel, each using the 8 cores available on the machine, we would be running 8 * 8 = 64 parallel processes - that would for sure overload our computer. What happens internally is that for the outer layer, `availableCores()` equals eight (8), whereas for the inner layer it equals one (1).
>
> Now, we could imagine that we process the outer layer with, say, two parallel futures, and then the inner layer with four parallel futures. In that case, we would end up running on at most eight cores (= 2 * 4). This can be achieved by forcing a fixed number of workers at each layer (not recommended):
>
> ```
> plan(list(tweak(multiprocess, workers = 2), tweak(multiprocess, workers = 4)))
> ```

Comment: Is there a reason why the tweak with a set number of workers for each layer isn't recommended?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve parallel processing like your expected figure,  [future.callr](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future.callr) is the choice. 
Just use:

`library(future.callr) 
plan(list(callr, callr))`

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about callr and future.callr!

Comment: It's actually a bug that the [future.callr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future.callr) package (I'm the author) does not protect against recursive parallel processing. This will be fixed in the next release https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future.callr/issues/4.